# Clustering From Minimum Spanning tree java

Tags: cluster-analysis, minimum-spanning-tree

i have to compare words according to their cosine similarity and produce k clusters from them with the similarity in terms of meaning. Basically i have a words like below:

```
[directors, producers, film, movie, black, white, man, woman, person, man, young, woman, science, fiction, thrilling, realistic, lovely, stunning, criminals, zombies, father, son, girlfriend, boyfriend, nurse, soldier, professor, college]
```

I have calculated their cosine similarity with each other in a complete weighted graph in which the cosine similarity is the edge weight and found the MST of this graph like below:

```
son criminals 7.622005318852533E-5
directors film 0.00269683524940825
college thrilling 0.004318332211016577
lovely girlfriend 0.011496356899859533
producers science 0.011946913151506599
nurse person 0.01222182619788835
fiction criminals 0.019032592497457333
film producers 0.021182908439749612
college fiction 0.02777607695416014
woman criminals 0.028081533433767823
realistic producers 0.028614429314768274
fiction film 0.031228743740582716
woman stunning 0.034664134514120794
college zombies 0.04113726420938837
criminals black 0.0442203277881683
professor science 0.04546819590424154
zombies soldier 0.04787773897201146
boyfriend stunning 0.04931897200102598
white producers 0.04969833492364299
nurse girlfriend 0.0498423837867863
thrilling nurse 0.05126380652206475
movie science 0.05220609189928112
nurse man 0.05229834114709604
movie young 0.07777548636454826
father nurse 0.13334569901132612
```

I need to get result similar to that(lets say for 2 clusters):

```
boyfriend,college,father,girlfriend,man,nurse,person,professor,son,woman,young

criminals,directors,fiction,film,lovely,movie,producers,science,stunning,thrilling,zombies
```

In my assigment it says that, "Once you have a weighted graph, you can find the
minimum spanning tree and cut k-1 edges that have the minimum weights on the graph to obtain
k clusters."
**The problem is that i am kind of confused and stucked what to do now? How should i obtain the resulting 2 clusters for instance that contains similar words in each cluster?**  Any idea or hint is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify where exactly you are stuck? Are you stuck on how to find the minimum spanning tree? Or are you stuck on how to discard the minimum weights to get k clusters?

Comment: @sprinter İ have got the MST as it is seen above, however stucked on clustering part as you described

Comment: Ok then it's pretty simple from that point. If you want 2 clusters then just remove the lowest weighted link (i.e son-criminal): you now have 2 connected graphs. All vertices in those 2 graphs are your clusters.

Answer (score 1):

With cosine, make sure to not mix up signs.

If you use cosine similarity, you'll need the *maximum* spanning tree instead (highest similarities). With cosine distance, the minimum is fine. You probably have this wrong right now.

One way to extract partitions out of a *minimum* spanning tree is to remove the *longest* edges (largest distance, remove the smallest similarities on a maximum spanning tree).

But there are many more to be found in clustering. This approach is essentially *Single-Link hierarchical clustering*. The MST can be visualized as a dendrogram, and there are probably a dozen ways to 'cut' this dendrogram into clusters.